# Selenium - remember credentials using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have this simple Selenium script in Java below (for Chrome).

All I am trying to do is:
1. login to website A, and remember my credentials (equal to clicking "yes" on "remember me" pop up in a browser) 
2. Turn off selenium
3. Turn on browser manually and still being logged in

Is there any way to do this?
I have seen several similar questions on stackoverflow, but haven´t managed to make the solutions work in my case.

Help would be appreciated.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyTestLogin {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://backup/Automation/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

    //login to a website A
    driver.get("https://websitea.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("name.surname");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Huhuhu");
    driver.findElement(By.className("flatbutton")).click();     

    driver.quit();

}

}
```

EDIT://
Heureka!

After a lot of rewrites & plentiful help from StackOverflow, I was finally able to write a script (and use an array as a  way of telling him which files to copy) which does exactly what it should - problem is, it is not working.

When I do the following:

1. open browser manually, clean private data, close browser
2. open browser manually, login to all the pages from the script manually, close browser
3. make a backup of the files mentioned in the script
4. open browser manually, clean private data, close browser
5. let the script run

Browser still does not remember me. But when instead of step 5 I copy the backed files from step 3 manually, it is working.

What am I missing?

```
            import java.io.File;
            import java.nio.file.Files;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
            import java.util.Arrays;

            import org.openqa.selenium.By;
            import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
            import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
            import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

            public class MyTestLogin {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://backup/Automation/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

                    //Create a new temporary folder to store all the cookies and other website data
                    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C://Users/user/Desktop/files/cookies");
                    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);       

                    //login to a website A
                    driver.get("https://websitea.com");
                    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("name.surname");
                    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
                    driver.findElement(By.className("flatbutton")).click();     
                    //new tab
                    //((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");  

                    //login to a website B       
                    driver.get("https://websiteb.com");

                    driver.findElement(By.id("os_username")).sendKeys("name.surname");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("os_password")).sendKeys("password");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();

                    /*When you are finished logging in, close the browser
                    otherwise you´re unable to copy current session cookie */
                    driver.quit();

                    // now copy all the necessary files from a new folder to a browser´s cookie location        

                    //Have a list of files that needs to be copied      
                    java.util.List<String> names = Arrays.asList(
                            "Cookies",
                            "Cookies-journal",
                            "Current Session", 
                            "Current Tabs",         
                            "Favicons",             
                            "Favicons-journal",
                            "History",
                            "History Provider Cache",               
                            "History-journal",
                            "Last Session",
                            "Last Tabs",
                            "Login Data",
                            "Login Data-journal",
                            "Network Action Predictor",
                            "Network Action Predictor-journal",
                            "Network Persistent State",             
                            "Origin Bound Certs",
                            "Origin Bound Certs-journal",
                            "Preferences",
                            "previews_opt_out.db",
                            "QuotaManager",             
                            "QuotaManager-journal",             
                            "Secure Preferences",
                            "Shortcuts",
                            "Shortcuts-journal",
                            "Top Sites",
                            "Top Sites-journal",
                            "Translate Ranker Model",
                            "TransportSecurity",                
                            "Visited Links",
                            "Web Data",
                            "Web Data-journal"              
                            );

                    // convert list to array       
                    String[] namesArr = new String[names.size()];
                    namesArr = names.toArray(namesArr);
                    //iterate over array and...     
                    int i=names.size();
                    int s=0;
                    while(i>=1){

                         //...for each item on the list, move it from one folder to another         

                            System.out.println(namesArr[s]);                

                            File sourceFile=new File ("C://Users/user/Desktop/Plocha/cookies/Default/"+namesArr[s]);
                            File destinationFile=new File("C://Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/"+namesArr[s]);
                                try{ 
                                    Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(),destinationFile.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                                    System.out.println("File copy successfull");                
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                                }
                                    s++;                                 
                                    i--;                           
                                }

                    //now delete the temporary folder
                    File directory = new File("C://Users/user/Desktop/Plocha/cookies/");

                    //make sure directory exists
                    if(!directory.exists()){

                       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
                       System.exit(0);

                    }else{

                       try{

                           delete(directory);

                       }catch(IOException e){
                           e.printStackTrace();
                           System.exit(0);
                       }
                    }

                    System.out.println("Done");
                }

                public static void delete(File file)
                    throws IOException{

                    if(file.isDirectory()){

                        //directory is empty, then delete it
                        if(file.list().length==0){

                           file.delete();
                           System.out.println("Directory is deleted : "
                                                             + file.getAbsolutePath());

                        }else{

                           //list all the directory contents
                           String files[] = file.list();

                           for (String temp : files) {
                              //construct the file structure
                              File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);

                              //recursive delete
                             delete(fileDelete);
                           }

                           //check the directory again, if empty then delete it
                           if(file.list().length==0){
                             file.delete();
                             System.out.println("Directory is deleted : "
                                                              + file.getAbsolutePath());
                           }
                        }

                    }else{
                        //if file, then delete it
                        file.delete();
                        System.out.println("File is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: You would have to get all cookies from session created by `WebDriver` and then, load these cookies in your own browser.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way that the original question changes. That invalidates all the answers. Instead, accept the answer that solved your first question and create a new question with the new problem.

Comment: But I haven´t modified the original question, I have simply added new info at the end. And the reason for that was because I couldn´t find "reply" button (so my answer would be depicted just aj Xlsx´s answer). Is there a way to do that? If yes, I will move the edited part there.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty folder to store all the cookies and other website data. You can tell the chrome webdriver to use this as folder by setting the user-data-dir argument.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/folder/");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to do that (see EDIT of my former post), but it is still not working, do you have any clue why?

Comment: Try setting the `user-data-dir` to your normal chrome data folder (might be `C://Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/`). You shouldn't need to copy any files.

Comment: Didn't help, after the script is run, the browser still does not remember me.

Comment: After bit of a googling, it seems the Default profile is the culprit, so by creating a new profile and telling Selenium to use that might do the trick. Do you, by any chance know how to do that in Selenium?

Comment: Scratch that, didn´t help. Creating new profile and telling selenium to use it´s folder as a cookie holder only improved things a little bit - when you load a page, it will prefill your login name (on some pages), but not your password, so I am stuck again. And I run out of options. I have no idea how to advance and make Chrome remember my credentials.

Comment: Does the website only use session cookies (if you close the browser completely, do you need to re-login)? Also, a chrome extension might be better in this case. [Auto Login](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-login/kjdgohfkopafhjmmlbojhaabfpndllgk?hl=en) could be useful

Comment: No, in vast majority of the pages I use I do not need to re-login (for example gmail account). I will check out that extension, thank you.